# Pinch zoom bounce to particular location in android

Tags: android

I have tried the pinch zoom and drag in my app.I am facing two issues.
1.On first touch the image move to some other position.Drag action works from that changed position.
2.During zooming the image bounce to particular location and drag action works for particular bound after jumps.This issue occurs occasionally not frequently.
Here is my code

```
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    float scale;

    // Dump touch event to log
    dumpEvent(event);

    // Handle touch events here...
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: //first finger down only
           // savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: //first finger lifted
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: //second finger lifted
            mode = NONE;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: //second finger down
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
            if (oldDist > 5f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) { //movement of first finger


                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);

                /*if (view.getLeft() >= -392){
                    matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
                }*/
            }
            else if (mode == ZOOM) { //pinch zooming
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                if (newDist > 5f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    // Perform the transformation
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

    return true; // indicate event was handled
}

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    String names[] = { "DOWN" , "UP" , "MOVE" , "CANCEL" , "OUTSIDE" ,
            "POINTER_DOWN" , "POINTER_UP" , "7?" , "8?" , "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_" ).append(names[actionCode]);
    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
            || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        sb.append("(pid " ).append(
                action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")" );
    }
    sb.append("[" );
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
        sb.append("#" ).append(i);
        sb.append("(pid " ).append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=" ).append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append("," ).append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";" );
    }
    sb.append("]" );
    Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want zoom image on imageview than you can use [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library.

Comment: dude I have tried this example but the image view gets blink during zooming

Comment: I have implemented i didnt face that issue